# Overlaying image on live feed in android

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing, overlay

I want to overlay an image on live feed in android. Can anyone suggest where to to start from?
I have converted the desired url to an image. Below is the code:

ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("https://www.google.com.pk/logos/classicplus.png");
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }
```

Now, what i want is how to overlay this image on to a desired region in a video i.e the hand detected area. and the problem is that this region of interest can move as it is a live feed....
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Relative layout and view.layout() method is your friends

Comment: Do i have to convert the imageview to bitmap first to overlay it on the video

Comment: How do you play video? Create RelativeLayout, put VideoView & ImageView inside it. Set ImageView location via layout method.

Comment: No basically i'm using a native camera below is the code: public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID);
        if (mCamera.isOpened()) {
            (new Thread(this)).start();
        } else {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open native camera");
        }
    }         and 'm using the layout provided by opencv which is basically a code(view) with no xml file

Answer (score 0):

I do it with by overlaying two views (named Preview and Overlay below). One takes care of the camera preview, the other controls a canvas to draw anything I want.

In `res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/toplevelframe"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
    <your.project.Preview
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <your.project.Overlay
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity class, `onCreate()`:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mPreview = (Preview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
mOverlay = (Overlay) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
...
```

in `onResume()`:

```
...
mCamera = Camera.open();
mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
...
```

in `onPause()`:

```
if (mCamera != null) {
    mPreview.setCamera(null);
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
```

Class `Overlay` extends View and draws on a canvas. There is nothing special, just override `onDraw()`.

For the camera preview class (`Preview` below), check the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview) for examples. It looks like this:

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...
  private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
  private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
  private Camera mCamera;
...
  public Preview(Context context, AttributeSet aset) {
      ...
      mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
      addView(mSurfaceView);
      // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
      // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
      mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
      mHolder.addCallback(this);
      mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
  }
...
  public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
      mCamera = camera;
      if (mCamera != null) {
          mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
          requestLayout();
      }
   }
...
}
```

and then implement all the methods of [SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) too.